# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 , I don't understand?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting this error while im sure the array is not null, here is the code :

```
            REPORT.info("Removing meta_field id {} from metamodel id {}", Integer[]{oldMetaFieldId, metamodelId);

            App.get(MetamodelFieldService.class).remove(metamodelId, new Integer[]{oldMetaFieldId});
```

I put the report just before the call of the method "remove" to make sure the variable oldMetaFieldId is not null, and it is not I checked the logs :

```
2023-06-20 15:12:21,776  INFO [main] FusionChampsFiches - Removing meta_field id [1007] from metamodel id 215
```

Here is the implementation of the "remove" method :

```
  public void remove(Integer metamodelId, Integer[] metaFieldIdList) {
    for (Integer metaFieldId : metaFieldIdList) {
      MetamodelField ex = new MetamodelField();
      ex.setMetamodelId(metamodelId);
      ex.setMetaFieldId(metaFieldId);
      List<MetamodelField> entityList = getDao().findByExample(ex);

      entityList.get(0);
      remove(entityList.get(0));
    }
    MetaModelCache.getCache().clear(getApplicationSession());
  }
```

I don't understand why i'm getting this error

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length
> 0

Comment: ` entityList` seems to be empty -> thats way you can not get the 0. element in ` entityList.get(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to a `List` being `null`, it might also be *empty* (contain nothing). In this case that is exactly the problem. There is nothing in the `List`, so you can't get the first element (there isn't one). One solution, check for empty. Like,

```
List<MetamodelField> entityList = getDao().findByExample(ex);
if (!entityList.isEmpty()) {
    entityList.get(0);
    remove(entityList.get(0));
}
```

Or use an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). Like,

```
List<MetamodelField> entityList = getDao().findByExample(ex);
Iterator<MetamodelField> iter = entityList.iterator();
if (iter.hasNext()) {
    MetamodelField mf = iter.next();
    iter.remove();
}
```